# ¿Por qué se está creando la barra de desplazamiento horizontal?

Tags: html, css, scroll

Venía bien diseñando el index, y de repente me apareció el scroll horizontal en el navegador. Vamos, tuve que borrar casi toda la página para intentar solucionarlo. Y no hay caso. *De seguro es una pavada, pero la verdad que no sé.*

```
<div class="carrousel__container">
    <!-- <img src="media/mdatacenter.jpg" alt="" class="carrousel__image1"> -->
</div>

<div class="carrousel__container">
    <!-- <img src="media/mdatacenter.jpg" alt="" class="carrousel__image1"> -->
</div>

<div class="carrousel__container">
    <!-- <img src="media/mdatacenter.jpg" alt="" class="carrousel__image1"> -->
</div>
```

EL CSS:

```
*{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: "Exo 2";
}

body{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
  
}

.carrousel__container{
    width: 90%;
    height: 40%;
    background-color: black;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 1px;

}
```

> No pongo lo demás, puesto que elimine todos los elementos css. ¡La imagen dentro del div (carrousel container) está comentada!

Cuando los elementos son varios y sobrepasan la altura de la pantalla, está bien, se crea el scroll vertical. Pero no entiendo **¿por qué el horizontal?**
Se me queda un pedazo de pantalla en horizontal que no sé de dónde sale. Ya borré márgenes, saqué los padding, busqué lo del colapso de márgenes... No sé qué sucede.

> Aclaro que hay conceptos fundamentales que no conozco de css. No sé si el body debe ser configurado de esa manera o no!

Podría solucionarlo con un `overflow : hidden`, pero no es la solución que busco, puesto que quisiera que los números me den correctamente, sino ya pasar al responsive va a ser un lío.

Comment: A simple vista a tu CSS todo está muy bien. Pero que tal si intentas con `width: calc(100% - 1rem)` a tu `carrousel__container` ? De otra forma, ve si en tu HTML no haya estilos en línea y otra hoja de estilos enlazado

Comment: Click derecho en tu página y pones `inspeccionar`, el navegador si divide en dos. En un lado queda tu pagina y en el otro el código. Si posicionas el mouse sobre el código en la pagina si visualiza el elemento correspondiente marcando además los margin y padding. De esta manera encuentras el elemento que está generando el scroll

Comment: Hola gracias muchachachos!! Lo hice!! Tanto el margin como el padding esta todo seteado en 0. No hay estilos en linea en el html. Y todo el codigo demas restante esta comentado, para tratar de verificar el problema. En el inspector me marca un body de 600px y el elemento carrousel__container tambien con 600px. Pero el scroll lateral se sigue visualizando. Habra alguna configuracion que este pasandome por alto ?

Comment: La altura tiene algo que ver ? Hablo desde mi ignorancia en css!! Si los elementos no sobresalen de la altura del viewport , el ancho se muestra normal y perfecto. No hay desbordamiento. El mismo ocurre cuando hay mas elementos debajo. Lo logico seria el scroll vertical. Pero yo tengo ambos!!

Comment: Probe en chrome pensando que era algo de cache o el navegador , pero se visualiza igual. Asi que evidentemente hay algo que me estoy pasando por alto.

Comment: Bueno!! Aparentemente no tiene que ver con mi codigo css!! Probe desde 0 con un html basico, y efectivamente al haber mas de 3 elementos en vertical, se me muestran ambos SCROLL , me llama la atencion que hay todavia un pedazo de pantalla que se mueve en horizontal. Seran uno 11 pixeles. Asi que si alguno sabe porque sucede esto se lo agradezco. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

A ver: lo solucioné seteando el ancho del `body{width : 100%}` usando porcentaje en vez de usar viewport width.
*Sinceramente el problema está porque no asimilo bien todavía estos conceptos.*

Pero ese pedazo de pantalla que se mueve en horizontal, es el ancho del scroll vertical que muestra cuando hay más elementos debajo.

> Estuve 1 día entero tratando de solucionar esto.
> Me da vergüenza jajaja

Answer (score 0):

Tuve un caso similar y lo pude solucionar con los siguiente:

```
overflow-x: hidden;
```

También puedes usar el overflow-y dependiendo de la ubicación de la barra.